# Show that there are no squares included in the sequences

Tags: number-theory, relations, quotient-spaces

Show that there are no squares included in in the sequences

(11, 111, 1111, 11111, ....)

(22, 222, 2222, 22222, ....)

(33, 333, 3333, 33333, ....)

and so on and so forth for all numbers $1 \rightarrow 9$

I was thinking about showing that because 11 is not square then some modulo 11, or 111, etc... is not square. Something like that, but I'm getting all these definitions mixed up in my head.

Any help to kickstart me in the right direction?

Comment: HINT: $$\underbrace{11\cdots 11}_{ n\ge2 \text{ digits}}\equiv-1\pmod4$$

Comment: Hmm, I like that but I really have no idea how to apply it to a proof. Ugh, please help. I'm so confused.

Comment: please find my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have commented $\displaystyle\underbrace{11\cdots11}_{n(\ge 2)\text{ digits}}\equiv11\pmod4\equiv-1\pmod 4$

But, any integer $a\equiv0,\pm1,2\pmod4\implies a^2\equiv0,1\pmod4$

So, $\displaystyle\underbrace{11\cdots11}_{n(\ge 2)\text{ digits}}$ can not be perfect Sqaure

Now, $\displaystyle99\cdots99$ and $\displaystyle44\cdots44$ will be square if and only if  $\displaystyle11\cdots11$  is perfect square

$\displaystyle22\cdots22;66\cdots66;88\cdots88$  will not be perfect square as the highest power of $2$ are odd

For the same reason,  $\displaystyle55\cdots55;77\cdots77$  will not be perfect square

Comment: And $3$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $5$, for the final case.

Comment: I'm marking it but still having trouble putting all the pieces together

Comment: @mharris7190, please pintpoint your confusion & don't accept until satisfied

Comment: How do you get a negative remainder? Shouldn't 11 = 3 (mod 4)?

Comment: @mharris7190, In congruence(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html), $-1\equiv3\pmod4$ We can safely write $3$ in place of $-1$

Comment: I got passed 11,etc.. and 22,etc.. because they are congruent to 3 and 2 (mod 4) respectively. Now I get to 33..33 and get congruent to 1 (mod 4). But I don't get your explanation.

Comment: What do you mean the highest power of 2 will be odd. And that also for that same reason, 55...55; 77...77 will not be perfect square.

Comment: @mharris7190, observe that $\displaystyle22\cdots22;66\cdots66$ are divisible by $2,$ but not by $4$.  $\displaystyle88\cdots88$ is divisible by $8=2^3,$ not by $2^4$  Similarly, $55\cdots55$  is divisible by $5,$ not by $5^2$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11594/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-mharris7190)